# Converting SQL Server query to Entiry Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

I need to convert a SQL query to Entity Framework

Sort the values ​​of a field `{'115-F-G', '10 -H-G ', '98 -T-R'}` in ascending order.

```
SELECT * FROM ReportePedido 
Where PedidoId =145 
Order By TipoProducto, 
 CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(EnderecoEstoque, 0, CHARINDEX('-',EnderecoEstoque,1)))
```

Result: `'10 -H-G ','98 -T-R','115-F-G'`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy to write as a Linq query, ordering part doesn't seem to worth to be done on server side, it could easily be done on client side:

```
var query = ctx.ReportePedido 
            .Where(r => r.PedidoId == 145)
            .AsEnumerable() 
            .OrderBy(r => r.TipoProducto),
            .ThenBy(r => int.TryParse(r.Split('-')[0], out int i)?i:int.MaxValue)
```